Couldnt get long lived access token from Instagram Login graph api
I am using instagram graph api on my web app, with business permissions(instagram_business_basic instagram_business_content_publish, instagram_business_manage_comments, instagram_business_manage_messages), i am able to get access token and get media and do stuff, but this token last only an hour, so i need a longer lived access token, but when i try try to get longer lived access token as stated in docs, I get the response
Sorry, this content isn't available right now
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.instagram.com/access_token
  ?grant_type=ig_exchange_token
  &client_secret=<YOUR_INSTAGRAM_APP_SECRET>
  &access_token=<VALID_SHORT_LIVED_ACCESS_TOKEN>"

Response
Sorry, this content isn't available right now
